# Is the set of points with smallest stabilizer open?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a complex reductive group acting linearly on a complex affine variety $X$, and let $K$ be the kernel of the action, i.e.
$$K:=\{g\in G:g\cdot x=x\text{ for all }x\in X\}.$$
Is 
$$X_K:=\{x\in X:\mathrm{Stab}_G(x)=K\}$$
Zariski-open in $X$?

Comment: You are correct, I am wrong!  Sorry about that.  I will delete that comment.

Comment: By the same argument as in the following case, there is a maximal open subscheme of $X$ over which the stabilizers are finite: 
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277874/variations-of-finite-stabilizer-in-the-action-of-an-algebraic-group-on-an-affine However, as you can see from the case of the standard scalar action of $\mathbb{G}_m$ on $\mathbb{A}^n$, that open subscheme need not be affine . . .

Comment: I keep thinking about this question, but I do not have an answer.  If the open subscheme were affine, then Luna's 'etale slice theorem would solve the problem, as in Friedrich Knop's solution of the earlier question.  However, I do not see how to reduced to that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is affirmative if $G$ is finite or abelian since in that case subgroups are rigid.

Otherwise, $X_K$ may not even be dense, let alone open. The standard example is due to Luna from his slice paper: Let $G=SL(2,\mathbb C)$ act on the space $X=S^3\mathbb C^2$ of binary cubics. The action is effective so $K=1$. Every non-degenerate cubic $f$ is the product of $3$ *distinct* linear factors. Then $Stab_G(f)$ contains the cyclic permutation of these factors which shows that $X_K$ is not dense. It is not empty either, since $f=x^2y$ has trivial stabilizer.

In my opinion, the question is ill-posed since $X_K$ may be open for the trivial reason that it is empty. Let, e.g., $G$ be absolutely simple (e.g. $G=SO(2n+1,\mathbb C)$) and $H$ a proper reductive subgroup. Then $X=G/H$ is affine with $K=1$ but $Stab_G(x)\ne K$ for all $x\in X$.

The way to go is to look at the stabilizers of only the closed orbits. Their behavior is much more regular which gives rise to the Luna stratification.

Comment: That makes me feel a lot better.  In that example, the open subset on which $G$ acts properly discontinuously is non-affine: the complement in $S^3\mathbb{C}^2$ of the image of the Veronese map $v_3:\mathbb{C}^2\to S^3\mathbb{C}^2$.  It is also not a union of $G$-invariant open affines.  The open has precisely two orbits, one of which is open and one of which is (relatively) closed.  So the smallest $G$-invariant open that contains the (relatively) closed orbit, i.e., the orbit of points with trivial stabilizer, contains the entire "proper-discontinuous open" (and thus is not affine).

Comment: @Jason Starr: Probably you mean the open subset on which $G$ acts with finite stabilizers. The action on this set is in general not properly discontinuous.

Comment: Yes, I meant the open subset on which $G$ acts with finite stabilizers.